# Different behavior on escaping double quotes

Tags: shell

I have a empty variable. When I do

`if [[  -z "$value" ]]; then echo "hello"; fi`

the output is hello

However, when I escape double quotes, i.e.

`if [[ -z \"$value\" ]]; then echo "hello"; fi`

hello is not printed on the screen.

What is the difference between above two commands?

Comment: The backslashes?  The second passes a double quote, followed by nothing and a double quote as the argument to be tested for emptiness, and two double quotes are not an empty string.  The first passes an empty string; the quotes are removed, and the empty string is an empty string.

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate which shell you're using. I'm guessing bash, but I don't want to assume.

Comment: Escaping the quotes changes them from syntactic (providing an instruction to the shell on how to understand other data) to literal (being data themselves). Because you're then passing the quotes themselves as data, the data given as an argument to the test can never be null.

Comment: What were you expecting escaping the quotes to do, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the in the first statement, the variable is expanded and the resulting statement is null.

Whereas in the second it expands to `""`. To see the difference consider the two echo statements,

```
$ echo "$value"

$ echo \"$value\"
""
```

The first one is null where as the second is not.

Answer (score 1):

There are three kind of quotes in Shell.

1. Single quote(' ')

   > All special characters between these quotes lose their special meaning.

   so `echo '$VALUE'`

   will literally print `$VALUE`because $loses its special meaning
   inside single quotes.
2. double Quotes(" ")

   > Most special characters between these quotes lose their special meaning with some exceptions  like $ among others.
3. Back Quote ()

   > Anything in between back quotes would be treated as a command and would be executed.

   **Backslash**

   > Any character immediately following the backslash loses its special meaning.

so in your case when you say `\"$value\"` because of backslash double quotes will loose meaning and will be evaluated as it is.

e.g if you have `value=34`  then   `\"$value\"` will evaluate to `"34"` with the double quotes. and if value is null as in your case then `\"$value\"` will evaluate to `""`

so it is not  null but a string with double quotes and that's why fail your null check.

Answer (score 0):

`if [[  -z "$value" ]]; then echo "hello"; fi` checks if the string value in the variable `$value` is non-empty.  But `if [[ -z \"$value\" ]]; then echo "hello"; fi` (assuming `$value` does not contain whitespace) checks if the string that starts with a `"` and ends with a `"` is non-empty.  But it never is, because it always contains at least two characters.